# Number of labelings of symmetric hexagonal tilings

Tags: tiling

I am searching for the Number of labelings of symmetric hexagonal tilings

If the hexagon is of the form P(n,n,n) then the coefficients can be found here 
[A217311](https://oeis.org/A217311)

I am looking for the coefficients of P(4,2,4)

After doing some research I found P(2,3,2),P(3,3,4),P(3,4,4)... and some others but not the one I am looking for

[image]

I took the img from
https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0004145.pdf

mathworld states that
[image]

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlanePartition.html

Using the above formula I can only calculate the first term which is 1764.

How can i find the other terms?

can anybody help me find the coefficients for P(4,2,4)?

thanx

Comment: You assume that notation $P(x,y,z)$ means something to anybody reading your title or your first sentence. This is evidently not the case. You should refer to a real explanation, not OEIS.

Comment: I edited my post... thank you

Comment: Please type out the table and the quoted MathWorld page since "images aren't SEO friendly".  See [this post on meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155601/259305) for further info.